# How I can change the database variable name in wp-config.php in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for the academy section of my website. The database of the academy section is different from my website's database but unfortunately I have used the DB_NAME variable for defining database name in my main website's config file which is same in wp-config file. Since I need to access both the databases at any time and any page no matter it belongs to the academy section or to the main website, it's giving me error of can't select the database. Can any one suggest how I can change the DB_NAME variable to something else in wp-config file to avoid the conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple WordPress installs in one database, as long as they have different prefixes. You can change the prefix in your wp_config.php on line 69 to something you'd like:

```
$table_prefix  = 'your_desired_prefix_';
```